I am getting this error whenever I run program with pytorch

The NVIDIA driver on your system is too old (found version 10010). Please update your GPU driver by downloading and installing a new version from the URL: http://www.nvidia.com/Download/index.aspx Alternatively, go to: https://pytorch.org to install a PyTorch version that has been compiled with your

I expect to run the program but instead it starts using CPU which becomes a lot slower for execution.

The error message seems pretty clear. Did you try to update your driver as it asks you to do?

Please provide your maximum supported CUDA version (shown with nvidia-smi) and the PyTorch version you tried to install on your machine.

Nvidia SMI
| NVIDIA-SMI 425.31       Driver Version: 425.31       CUDA Version: 10.1
Name: torch
Version: 2.1.0+cu118

According to your comment, the maximum CUDA version supported by your GPU is 10.1. You are using a PyTorch version shipped with a version 11.8 CUDA toolkit, which is higher than 10.1.
Therefore, you must install a Pytorch version compiled with a CUDA toolkit version lower or equal to 10.1. For your information, the latest PyTorch version that follows this requirement is 1.8.1 (one of them is compiled with a CUDA toolkit version of 10.1):
pip install torch==1.8.1+cu101 torchvision==0.9.1+cu101 -f https://download.pytorch.org/whl/torch_stable.html

Alternatively, you can update your CUDA driver, if your GPU allows it. In that case, your maximum supported CUDA version will be raised and you should be able to run on a PyTorch version > 1.8.1. Of course, this will depend on your new driver version.
